# push notification using only phonegap not using any .java file

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I am using a phonegap application and trying to put a push notification.I found many example over the net but the thing is I am using only phonegap mean only .html , .js , .css file so can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example discusses how to implement push using pushwoosh on Android: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/
If you do not have an AndroidManifest.xml file, you are not developing a Phonegap Android app.

Comment: I am using https://build.phonegap.com/ to build my app .AndroidManifest.xml is not needed only html file is enough to build my app using this site .

Comment: I had not understood that you were using Phonegap build. I have looked into the issue. The best I could find is over at https://github.com/shaders/pushwoosh-phonegap-build-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml. I am not sure if the Android section of this file will be useful.

Comment: @JANNURM did you manage to achieve push in your app? If so, please share how you did it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily integrate push notifications to your PhoneGap app with Pushwoosh. Check out the integration guide:

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

The plugin itself is on GitHUb and the integration is pretty easy.

Comment: But is for Ios tell me for android

Comment: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/ This should be the correct link.

Comment: I am using only .html .js .css file no .java file there is no 'AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: in this link ++http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/++ there are 3 folder  
1. Phonegap-Push.xcodeproj 2.Phonegap-Push 3.www  ++But as  I said I am using only .html .js .css file then only the "www" folder is runable for me so is it possible to run ??++

Comment: How do you create the application you can run on the device? Do you use PhonegapBuild?

Comment: PhoneGap Build would not let you add any push notifications yet. They are going to implement support for Pushwoosh plugin soon, but they really need to be pushed to allow any third party plugin.